# c# and XPath, need help extracting 2 pieces of text

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, xpath-2.0

The screenshot below shows 2 pieces of text (in red rectangles) that I need to extract from the attached html.  I was able to do a simple one but this is beyond me at the moment.

The text in the green rectangle is unique in the entire document and therefore can be used as a starting point to find the other 2.

At the bottom is all the html for the "section" element that can be used for this example.

Big thanks for any help I can get.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO8Vh.png)

```
<section class="details-portlet">
    <div data-auto="details-tile-title" class="details-portlet__title ">
        <i class="fa fa-book details-portlet__title-icon"></i>

        <h3 data-auto="Company Summary">Company Summary</h3>

    </div><div>
        <div class="details-portlet__columns--seperator">
            <div class="details-portlet__col " data-auto="Contact">
                <div class="portlet-content details-shared-tile details-shared-tile__main ">
                    <div class="portlet-content__col--vert-centered portlet-content__col details-shared-tile__icon-col" title="Contact"><i class="fa fa-address-card-o portlet-content__icon"></i></div><div class="portlet-content__col--vert-centered portlet-content__col" data-auto="icon-tile-data">
                        <address data-auto="details-contact">
                            <div data-auto="details-contact-name" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                                <div class="details-shared-tile__main" style="margin-right: 5px;">Alexander Burd</div>
                                <div>
                                    <div class="edit-icon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil contact-edit-icon" data-auto="edit-contact"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>Sales Exec, Finance Exec <div class="custom-contact" data-auto="mmdb-email"><a href="mailto:undefined"></a></div><div class="custom-contact" data-auto="details-custom-contact"></div>
                        </address>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><div class="details-portlet__col " data-auto="Address"><div class="portlet-content details-shared-tile details-shared-tile__main "><div class="portlet-content__col--vert-centered portlet-content__col details-shared-tile__icon-col" title="Address"><i class="fa fa-map-marker portlet-content__icon"></i></div><div class="portlet-content__col--vert-centered portlet-content__col" data-auto="icon-tile-data"><address data-auto="details-address"><div class="details-shared-tile__main">1177 West Loop S # 1400</div><div class="details-shared-tile__main">Houston, TX 77027</div><div data-auto="details-address-maplink"><a class="details-shared-tile__link">Map / Street View</a></div></address></div></div></div>
        </div><div class="details-portlet__columns--seperator"><div class="details-portlet__col " data-auto="Phone"><div class="portlet-content details-shared-tile details-shared-tile__main "><div class=" portlet-content__col details-shared-tile__icon-col" title="Phone"><i class="fa fa fa-phone portlet-content__icon"></i></div><div class=" portlet-content__col" data-auto="icon-tile-data">(713) 961-7777</div></div></div><div class="details-portlet__col " data-auto=" Website"><div class="portlet-content details-shared-tile details-shared-tile__main "><div class=" portlet-content__col details-shared-tile__icon-col" title=" Website"><i class="fa fa fa-link portlet-content__icon"></i></div><div class=" portlet-content__col" data-auto="icon-tile-data"><a target="_blank" href="http://713abogado.com" title="713abogado.com">713abogado.com</a></div></div></div></div>
    </div><div class="details-portlet__columns company-summary-data"><div class="details-portlet__col"><div style="width: 100%;"><div class="details-portlet__data-columns" data-auto="data-column"><div data-auto="Industry-(SIC)" class="details-portlet__data-cat" style="width: 33%;">Industry (SIC)</div><div data-auto="Industry-(SIC)-data" class="details-portlet__col">Attorneys (8111-03)</div></div><div class="details-portlet__data-columns" data-auto="data-column"><div data-auto="Location-Type" class="details-portlet__data-cat" style="width: 33%;">Location Type</div><div data-auto="Location-Type-data" class="details-portlet__col">Single Loc</div></div><div class="details-portlet__data-columns" data-auto="data-column"><div data-auto="Social" class="details-portlet__data-cat" style="width: 33%;">Social</div><div data-auto="Social-data" class="details-portlet__col"><a title="Facebook" href="//www.facebook.com/713abogado" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square social-links__facebook"></i></a></div></div></div></div><div class="details-portlet__col"><div style="width: 100%;"><div class="details-portlet__data-columns" data-auto="data-column"><div data-auto="Sales-Volume" class="details-portlet__data-cat" style="width: 33%;">Sales Volume</div><div data-auto="Sales-Volume-data" class="details-portlet__col">$5,094,000</div></div><div class="details-portlet__data-columns" data-auto="data-column"><div data-auto="Employees" class="details-portlet__data-cat" style="width: 33%;">Employees</div><div data-auto="Employees-data" class="details-portlet__col">20</div></div></div></div></div>
</section>
```